# Asp.net cache not working

Tags: asp.net, caching, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to configure cache in sharepoint site. I have write a method but its not working for me.

```
private string GetTopNavigationHtml()
    {

        var navigationHtml = HttpContext.Current.Cache["TopNavigationCacheKey"] as string;
        navigationHtml = BuildNavigationHtml();
        bool doRefreshCache = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["RefreshCache"]);
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("TopNavigationCacheKey", navigationHtml, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(navigationHtml))
        {
            navigationHtml = BuildNavigationHtml();
            HttpContext.Current.Cache["TopNavigationCacheKey"] = navigationHtml;
        }

        return navigationHtml;
    }
```

This is my method. Whenever I changed any item in list it also update the cache. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does "it's not working for me" mean?

Comment: Means data is not loading from cache.

Comment: Every time it loads from List.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you trying to do is something like this?

1. Check if the cache has not exist or there's a querystring of "RefreshCache"
2. If true, create cache.
3. Either way, return the existing cache at the end.

   ```
   private string GetTopNavigationHtml()
   {
       bool doRefreshCache = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["RefreshCache"]);

       if(HttpContext.Current.Cache[TopNavigationCacheKey] == null || doRefreshCache)
       {
           var navigationHtml = BuildNavigationHtml();
           HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("TopNavigationCacheKey", navigationHtml, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero);
       }

       return HttpContext.Current.Cache[TopNavigationCacheKey] as string;
   }
   ```

Comment: I want something like that, But its not working in my case.

Comment: Do you want to try add in `CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable` parameter to ensure it is not cleared due to lack of system memory?

Comment: I tried to add this parameter. But this generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

No sure but did you try checking "Cache" setting in SharePoint site as given here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-object-cache-settings-cef3a1f7-4493-496d-9396-9da3a4d5bab7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm1